# Spring security Skip saving SecurityContext since saving on response commited is disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

i have Async Web Services in Jersey, with a Spring Security, and all run into Tomcat Container.

I have this problem, when i start Tomcat all works, i can call my API and i have the response. The problem is when i'm not call nothing for example 1 hour and after i try to call one API i have this error:

```
(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:148) - Skip saving SecurityContext since saving on response commited is disabled
```

Why? is Tomcat config problem? or Spring config problem?

My Tomcat config is:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
    clientAuth="true" keystoreFile="/home/antonio/Documenti/keystore/server.jks" 
    keystorePass="secret" maxThreads="200" port="8443" 
    protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    truststoreFile="/home/antonio/Documenti/keystore/servertruststore.jks" 
    truststorePass="secret"/>
```

Example for API:

```
@Path("/getA")
@POST
@ManagedAsync
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void lists(RequestData  dataRequest,@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) throws JSONException {


    service = (ServicesSt) ctx.getAttribute(services);

    jdbcStudent =  (PersonJDBCTemplate) ctx.getAttribute(dbStudent);


    response.setTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    ListenableFuture<Result<Exam>> listsEx = service
            .getTestsInterfaceAsync(dataRequest.getToken(),jdbcStudent);

    Futures.addCallback(listsEx, new FutureCallback<Result<Exam>>() {


        public void onSuccess(Result<Exam> tests) {
            response.resume(tests);
        }
```

My Security config is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- To allow public access by default and to set authentication mode to 
        basic login/password -->
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>


    <security:http auto-config="true" >
        <security:http-basic/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_DUMMY" requires-channel="https"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- To delegate authorization to method calls rather than to urls -->
    <!-- (Thus, we don't need to set any url-interceptor in this conf) 

    <security:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />-->

    <!-- To create user/password with roles -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user authorities="ROLE_DUMMY" name="user"
                    password="pass" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```